# Get NSTableView to register drop from PNG source

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, drag-and-drop, nspasteboard

Trying to get this to work, and not sure what I'm missing. The idea is to drop images on a `NSTableView` so that I can grab their paths and do some manipulations for them. I can get the drop to work for `NSPastebouardTypeString`, but I cannot for the life of me get it to register dragging PNGs from Finder into the tableview. What am I missing?

Relevent code:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [imageTableView registerForDraggedTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:NSPasteboardTypePNG]];
}

- (NSDragOperation)tableView:(NSTableView *)aTableView validateDrop:(id < NSDraggingInfo >)info proposedRow:(NSInteger)row proposedDropOperation:(NSTableViewDropOperation)operation {
    NSLog(@"Validate Drop");
    return NSDragOperationEvery;
}

- (BOOL)tableView:(NSTableView *)aTableView acceptDrop:(id < NSDraggingInfo >)info row:(NSInteger)row dropOperation:(NSTableViewDropOperation)operation {
    NSLog(@"Accept Drop");
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PNG *files* dragged from the Finder are *not* PNG data. They're *files*, which have their own pasteboard type. (Being files, you don't necessarily want them to be entirely loaded in memory in case of a drop, would you? :D)

10.4 gave you a NSArray of NSStrings as a `NSFilenamesPboardType`. 10.5 and later *also* provide you with an array of file: URLs as `NSURLPboardType`. Since you're using the older API, [this document on 10.5- APIs applies](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/PasteboardGuide106/Articles/pbUpdating105.html) (10.6 completely overhauls the pasteboard API to make it behave more like the iOS one).

Comment: Ok. I misunderstood then. Should I _not_ be using `NSURLPboardType` or `NSFileNamesPboardType` in 10.6? I didn't see a comperable 10.6 api. Just the `writefiles:` method, which I understood as being for dragging out, as opposed to dropping in.